# Jquery Load function not referring master page script files

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jquery load function in my application's **masterpage.html** and it is working fine. But the problem is i need to put Jquery.min.js in all my content pages in order to use jquery functionality in my content page. I don't want to include it in all pages. It should refer from my master page.

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadContent(pagename) 
    {
         $("#output").load(pagename);
    }
</script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="loadContent('about.html')">About</a>

<div id="output"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

**about.html**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
<div id="content">
This is about page !!
 </div>
```

As you see my **about.html** again am including jquery in order to use it in my about.html page. How to avoid this in all pages ? Please help

Comment: If about.html is being loaded with jquery, why do you need to include jquery again in about.html?

Comment: When i open my masterpage.html, I will click a link About, and it loads a page perfectly. But i face problem when i write the jquery functions like alert($("#username").val()) in about.html it will show error $ is undefined. then it forces to include jquery cdn in my about.html

Comment: Can you show the code of your failed attempt to do this i.e. about.html without including jquery, with a <script> element containing that alert?

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined comaccesscards:60
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined comaccesscards:112
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible . You have to include it in all pages where you are using jquery

Instead of referring to the url like below ,

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
```

You can download the jquery library to your project path and use it like

```
<script src="project_name/folder_name/jquery.min.js">
```

But it is compulsory to include jquery in all pages

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Yes i am including it in all my pages. Because of this am facing the applications performance issue like it is taking time to load the pages. As i am using kendo ui in my application. Please suggest me best partial rendering technique

Comment: In case of kendo ui my suggestion is to use the specific `jquery` files instead of adding the whole jquery . for example `you will have kendo datetime picker as separate jquery you can import it instead of using the total kendo ui`

Comment: Yes you are correct , I took custom minified scripts from kendo and tried. It gave me some performance but still i face problem while accessing from other servers. Actual script file size was 1.1 mb afterr custom script it is 450kb. But still i dont want to load it for every page. Please help me

Comment: No other way . you can avoid jquery in case if you are very basic operation . (i.e) `simple things can be done using javascript` so that no need to import jquery there

Comment: Not only jquery but i need to include all the Kendo Scripts which are required in particular page. :(

Comment: Do you know fast way to load script files ?

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326514/how-to-load-jquery-faster) and [this](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2012/02/17/stop-paying-your-jquery-tax) And also nice stuff [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/196428/issues-to-be-considered-while-loading-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you a best answer, these is my advice

1. the jQuery file had better include at the bottom in **body** tag.
2. If you use the jQuery,you must include it.

Comment: I have tried id by including all script files at bottom of the page but content div not referring the scripts from masterpage.html. So i need to include the scripts file reference in my all pages.